# To remember them

Tags: word, knowledge, visual, rebus

The answer to this puzzle consists of three words with a total of 13 letters. Combining what you see below should lead you to the correct answer.

---

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> ARC DE TRIOMPHE

First picture

> This is the "arc", the characteristic shape.

Second picture

> The first picture represent "to 84" or "284" which is the number of steps (second picture) to the top of the Arc de Triomphe (thanks to OP for explaining).

Third picture

> This picture refers to the two-letter codes representing the states of the USA in order (AL is Alabama, WY is Wyoming). The three in the middle represented by the boxes roughly represent the positions where Pennsylvania (PA), Rhode Island (RI) and South Carolina (SC) would appear. Taking the six letters and ignoring the last (notice the box with the X), this spells out **PARIS**

Title

> The Arc de Triomphe honours those who fought and died for France in the French Revolutionary and Napoleonic Wars, with the names of all French victories and generals inscribed on its inner and outer surfaces.

Comment: Well done! rot13(Sbe gur frpbaq cvpgher: Gur erpgnatyrf ercerfrag fgnvef. Naq gur qverpgvba fvta jnf vagraqrq nf "gb 84" - n yvy' jbeqcynl bs gjb. 284 vf gur gbgny ahzoref bs fgnvef bs gur ohvyqvat.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ah, that makes sense, thank you.